# How many intersections do the curves given by $y=a^x$ and $x=a^y$ have?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am trying to figure out how many intersections the curves given by $y=a^x$ and $x=a^y$ have for $a \in (0, \infty) \setminus \{1\}$. My approach is to notice $y=a^x>0$, $x=a^y>0$, rewrite
$$\ln{x}=\ln{a^y}$$
$$\ln{x}=y\ln{a}$$
$$y = {\ln{x} \over \ln{a}}$$
compare
$$a^x={\ln{x} \over \ln{a}}$$
$$f(x)=e^{x\ln{a}}-{\ln{x} \over \ln{a}}$$
and try to establish local extrema
$$f^{'}(x)=e^{x\ln{a}}\ln{a}-{1 \over x\ln{a}}=0$$
This is where I get stuck. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In particular, you want to solve $y=a^{a^y}$. Suppose first that $a>1$; then $f(y) = a^y$ is a strictly increasing function. So if $a^y>y$, then $a^{a^y} = f(a^y) > f(y)= a^y > y$; similarly, if $a^y < y$ then $a^{a^y} < a^y < y$. Consequently, the only way we could have $y=a^{a^y}$ is if $y=a^y$. A similar argument holds for $0<a<1$, since $a^y$ will be strictly decreasing.

It's not a hard calculus exercise to show that the equation $y=a^y$ has one solution if $0<a\le1$, two solutions if $1<a<e^{1/e}$, one solution if $a=e^{1/e}$, and no solutions if $a>e^{1/e}$. These solutions will correspond to the points of intersection you want.

(Note that the first paragraph is essentially proving that the graph of a function and its inverse function, when it exists, can only intersect on the diagonal $y=x$.)